# Parsing Hive DDL with Unicode representation

Tags: hadoop, unicode, hive, azure-hdinsight

I am migrating tables from Hive 1 to HDInsight Hive 2, and following lines in DDL are not parsed properly on recreation of tables from source on destination:

```
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ' '
COLLECTION ITEMS TERMINATED BY '\u0002'
MAP KEYS TERMINATED BY '\u0003'
```

Returned error is:

> Error: Error while compiling statement: FAILED: ParseException line 9:33 cannot recognize input near 'u0002' ''\nMAP KEYS TERMINATED BY '' 'u0003' in serde properties specification (state=42000,code=40000)

Answer (score 0):

The problem was not in second line, but in first. Just had to replace literal space character in FIELDS TERMINATED BY with '\u0020'.

```
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\u0020'
```